# How to create a hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a hyperlink in Google Sheets Script Editor without inserting that hyperlink into text anywhere. For context, I'm using a script to send out automated emails with unique links.

Is there a way to create a hyperlink without using the "=HYPERLINK" formula or replacing text in the actual document? All questions I've seen related to .setLinkUrl edit text within the document/spreadsheet, whereas I'm just trying to turn a variable into a hyperlink. Is this possible to do something like this?

```
  var url = "urltext.something.com/" + customLinkEnding;
  var urltext = "Click this Hyperlink!";
  var hyperlink = urltext.setLinkUrl(0, urltext.length, url);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'm using a script to send out automated emails with unique links.

If you use script for sending emails, you may just convert the message into HTML code and make hyperlinks and other formating.

See sample code here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: Thanks! I think I'd seen the documentation before, but hadn't looked through hard enough to find parameters for htmlbody. I'm obviously still learning, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.